# How to assign titles to paragraphs, followed by a line break?

Tags: paragraphs, sections-paragraphs

If I want to give a title to a paragraph I can just use `\paragraph{Respective Title} *Text*`

However, I cannot put a line break between the title and the text, since it would give a compilation error.

I'm looking for something like what can be see on this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_quantification#Sources_of_uncertainty).

Comment: Would something `\subsubsection*{Respective Title}` work? The `*` prevents it from being numbered.

Comment: Please mention the class name (i.e., `\documentclass{book}`) what you used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`titlesec` package can do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\paragraph}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}


\paragraph{title}

text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems the O.P. doesn't want paragraphs to be numbered…

Comment: @Bernard The paragraph is not numbered. See image, no number

Comment: And no message from the use of `\theparagraph`?

Comment: @Bernard What messege?

Comment: I don't know exactly – some warning, for instance, about `\secnumdepth`. Personally, I would have left arguments n°3 and 4 empty.

Comment: @Bernard No warning, try code yourself

Comment: There is a number, but you need `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}` to see it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but somehow I thought that there would be a more automatic way to do this... Anyway, thanks ;)